# Avro Map-Reduce on oozie

Tags: serialization, hadoop, mapreduce, avro, oozie

I have been trying to run a Avro map-reduce on oozie. I specify the mapper and reducer class in the workflow.xml and provide other configs too. But it gives out an

```
java.lang.RunTime Exception - class mr.sales.avro.etl.SalesMapper not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper
```

The same job when run directly on a hadoop cluster (and not via oozie) gets completed and gives the desired output. So it seems probable that I may be missing some oozie config. What I guess from the exception is that oozie requires the mapper to be a subclass of `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper` but Avro mappers have a different signature - they extend org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroMapper and this may be reason for the error.

So my question is how do I confiure oozie workflow/properties file to  allow it to run an Avro map-reduce job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AVRO, you'll need to configure a few extra properties:

- `org.apache.avro.mapred.HadoopMapper` is the actual mapper class you need to set (this implements the Mapper interface)
- `avro.mapper` property should name your `SalesMapper` class

There are other properties for the combiner and reducer too - check the AvroJob source and the utility methods.

Another way of doing this is to examine the job.xml from a job you manually submitted, and copy over the relevant configuration properties to your oozie workflow.xml

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could make the job run via oozie but the output doesn't seem to be in the binary avro format - it looks like a text file with entries of the kind org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper@448765ee

Can you suggest what went wrong, if it did? Because in the job I submitted manually, the output looked different. I have specified the outputscehma in workflow.xml

Comment: Well I had missed specified the output.format parameter. It worked when I specified it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem this week. Here is my workflow.xml (modified):

```
<workflow-app name='sample-wf' xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
<start to='start_here'/>
<action name='start_here'>
    <map-reduce>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <prepare>
            <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/output"/>
        </prepare>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                <value>/user/${wf:user()}/input</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                <value>/user/${wf:user()}/output</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.HadoopMapper</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.HadoopReducer</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>avro.mapper</name>
                <value>package.for.my.Mapper</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>avro.reducer</name>
                <value>package.for.my.Reducer</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.input.format.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroUtf8InputFormat</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.format.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroOutputFormat</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.key.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapoutput.key.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapoutput.value.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroValue</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>avro.map.output.schema</name>
                <value>{put your schema here from job.xml via manual run}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>avro.input.schema</name>
                <value>"string"</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>avro.output.schema</name>
                <value>{put your schema here from job.xml via manual run}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.key.comparator.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKeyComparator</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>io.serializations</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization,org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroSerialization</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </map-reduce>
    <ok to='end'/>
    <error to='fail'/>
</action>
<kill name='fail'>
    <message>MapReduce failed, error message[$sf:errorMessage(sf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name='end'/>
```

You may need to modify this a bit more depending on the inputs and outputs of your map-reduce job.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your mapper and reducer classes also? My oozie workflow is working fine, but the o/p file is not .avro file. 
Here is my workflow:

```js
<workflow-app name='sample-wf' xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
<start to='start_here'/>
<action name='start_here'>
    <map-reduce>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <prepare>
            <delete path="${nameNode}/user/hadoop/${workFlowRoot}/final-output-data"/>
        </prepare>
        <configuration>

            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                  <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
                  <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
                  <value>true</value>
                </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                <value>/user/hadoop/${workFlowRoot}/input-data</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                <value>/user/hadoop/${workFlowRoot}/final-output-data</value>
            </property>


            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.mapper.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.HadoopMapper</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.reducer.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.HadoopReducer</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>avro.mapper</name>
                <value>com.flipkart.flap.data.batch.mapred.TestAvro$CFDetectionMapper</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>avro.reducer</name>
                <value>com.flipkart.flap.data.batch.mapred.TestAvro$CFDetectionReducer</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.input.format.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>avro.schema.input.key</name>
                <value>{... schema ...}</value>
            </property>
           
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.mapoutput.key.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.AvroKey</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>avro.map.output.schema.key</name>
                <value>{... schema ...}</value>
            </property>

            
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.mapoutput.value.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
            </property>
             <property>
                <name>mapreduce.output.format.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKeyValueOutputFormat</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.output.key.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey</value>
            </property>

            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.output.value.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroValue</value>
            </property>
           
            
            <property>
                <name>avro.schema.output.key</name>
                <value>{ ....   schema .... }</value>
            </property>
             <property>
                <name>avro.schema.output.value</name>
                <value>"string"</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.output.key.comparator.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKeyComparator</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>io.serializations</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization,org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroSerialization
                </value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </map-reduce>
    <ok to='end'/>
    <error to='fail'/>
</action>
<kill name='fail'>
    <message>MapReduce failed, error message[$sf:errorMessage(sf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name='end'/>
</workflow-app>
```

And my mapper and reducer are defined like these :

```html
public static class CFDetectionMapper extends
                Mapper<AvroKey<AdClickFraudSignalsEntity>, NullWritable, AvroKey<AdClickFraudSignalsEntity>, Text> {}

 public static class CFDetectionReducer extends
               Reducer<AvroKey<AdClickFraudSignalsEntity>, Text, AvroKey<AdClickFraudSignalsEntity>, AvroValue<CharSequence>>
```